# Inconsistent Binary Data or Condition Statement Changing Data

Tags: c++, binary, conditional-statements

Really having some trouble even phrasing the problem. What's happening is I'm reading and storing an entire binary file into a uint32_t*. Then checking for the start of the segment of data I need. However, adding a check to just make sure I haven't passed over the array changes where the start of the segment is and I have no idea why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int* binmem = new int[32]; 
streampos size; // size of memblock 
int blocklength; // length memblock
uint32_t * memblock; // all data
int startpos; 
int endpos;  
int x;

void NewParticle() {
    startpos = 0;
    while (memblock[startpos]!= 0xff000000) { // 4278190080
        if (startpos > blocklength) {
            //cout << "nah";
            //x++;
            throw invalid_argument("No start of particle");
        }
        startpos++;
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ifstream file(argv[0], ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        size = file.tellg();
        blocklength = (size / 4) + (size % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        memblock = new uint32_t[size / 4 + (size % 4 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(memblock), size);
        file.close();
        NewParticle();
    } else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

startpos then varies depending on what condition statement I add into NewParticle(), eg. throwing the exception gives 1109 where as taking the condition out completely gives 812. Using the "nah" makes the while loop run forever and using the x++ statement causes a segment fault... Any idea how these could possibly be changing things? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Nothing you have inside `if (startpos > blocklength)` changes the data in the array, but if you comment out the `throw` there's nothing to terminate the loop, you might try `return` instead or put the termination check in the `while` itself.  When you say "gives X" what do you mean?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I had forgotten a closing bracket sorry, the issue is the anything inside the if statement shouldn't change the data regardless, the while loop should always stop at the same point for the same file at the same startpos value, but just inserting an if statement in the while loop changes the startpos value or the function behaviour and I have no idea why

Comment: The if statement doesn't change anything unless you're commenting out the throw at the same time leaving an infinite loop.  Have you considered the value doesn't exist in the file?  Are you sure you're looking for the right endian value?  [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf55a3d3d044db6) is an example of writing that value to a random place in a file and finding it again.  Perhaps that will help, but without having access to your data file I can't offer anything other than guesses.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the value does exist in the file I'm sure of it, and I find it and can output it to prove it as in your example but the issue is simply editing that if statement or taking it out entirely changes the point at which the value is found... where do you see an infinite loop? Are you referring to the case that the value is not found?

Comment: Perhaps checking to see if `read()` actually read as much as you want to assume it did would be a good thing. Similarly, checking the results of other method calls is generally recommended...

Comment: The if changes nothing.  I took your code with the file I created where I know the value exists, uncommented out all the lines in the if and it finds the value every time.  The only issue I see with your code is using `argv[0]` as a filename, meaning you're searching for the value in the currently running executable.  Use  `argv[1]` for the first command line parameter, and check `argc` to make sure there is actually a parameter there first.

Comment: There is one more thing.  If the value is in the file but not on a 4 byte boundary this code will not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to work if your input is a valid file.

As @RetiredNinja pointed out, possible problems are:

1. **Using `argv [0]` instead of `argv [1]`.**

   `argv [0]` will typically point to the name of the executable, which is probably not the file you wish to parse. If you are trying to parse your currently running executable to find your particles, then you have a bad design. So make this change:

   ```
   ifstream file(argv[1], ios::binary | ios::ate);
   ```

   Run your program like this (for Linux):

   ```
   ./myprogram file.bin
   ```

   or (for Windows):

   ```
   .\myprogram.exe file.bin
   ```

   Or change the default command line arguments in your IDE if you're trying to debug your program.
2. **The value `0xFF000000` is not on an aligned four-byte boundary.**

   For instance, the value could be spread across two `uint32_t`s in your array. This situation is a bit more complicated.
   You will have to basically iterate through your `uint32_t` array with a `char*` and look for a `0xFF` and see if you can find 3 `0x00` before or after it (depending on endianness).

The rest of this answer is just some minor recommendations. You can ignore the rest of this if you want. All of this below assumes problem 2 does not exist.

Here is how I generated a test file for your code:

```
void createBinFile (const std::string &file_name)
{
    // Some random data to use.
    const uint32_t sample_data [] = {
        0x000000cc,
        0x0000dd00,
        0x00ee0000,
        0xff000000,
        0x00000011,
        0x00002200,
        0x00330000,
        0x44000000,
    } ;

    // Write some binary data.
    std::ofstream file (file_name, std::ios::binary) ;
    file.write (reinterpret_cast <const char *> (sample_data), sizeof (sample_data)) ;
}
```

Managing your own memory is unnecessary. Here's a way to use a `std::vector <uint32_t>` instead of a raw `uint32_t*` array:

```
std::vector <uint32_t> loadBinFile (const std::string &file_name)
{
    std::ifstream file (file_name, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate) ;

    std::streampos size = file.tellg () ;
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg) ;

    unsigned padding = (size % sizeof (uint32_t) == 0) ? 0 : 1 ; // or throw exception 
    unsigned vec_size = size / sizeof (uint32_t) + padding ;

    std::vector <uint32_t> data (vec_size) ;
    file.read (reinterpret_cast <char*> (&data[0]), size) ;

    return data ;
}
```

And here's a quick driver that shows how to find your `0xFF000000` value. This requires you to `#include <algorithm>` for `std::find()`.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    const std::string file_name = argv [1] ;

    std::vector <uint32_t> data = loadBinFile (file_name) ;

    const uint32_t sentry_value = 0xff000000 ;

    typedef std::vector <uint32_t>::const_iterator const_iterator ;
    const_iterator citer = std::find (data.begin (), data.end (), sentry_value) ;

    if (citer != data.end ()) {
        std::cout << "Particle found!" "\n" ;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Particle not found!" "\n" ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```