# Is Binary Data Read The Same Every Time?

Tags: c++, file-io, binary, ifstream, sequential

In c++ using member function read() from ifstream does it process binary data sequentially and the same each time you read the same file? So if you were to read a file once and store data would it store it identically the second time in terms of order?

EDIT: 
Thanks for all the comments. The question came to me when I was storing the data read from a binary file in an array but accessing that stored data showed different values each time I did it. I wrote a more poorly worded and less concise question earlier today but still regarding the same issue. [Inconsistent Binary Data or Condition Statement Changing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086211/inconsistent-binary-data-or-condition-statement-changing-data)

Comment: It stores what you give it.  If you give it the same data repeatedly, it will store the same thing repeatedly.  BTW iostreams are not designed for binary data, they actually are pretty bad at it.  If you don't want a locale causing newline conversions and things like that, use the `<stdio.h>` APIs.  iostreams work on characters, not bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's being asked?  If reading the same file multiple times didn't produce the same data, then what would the point of a file system be?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Check again, the locale facets are implemented at the `streambuf` level and their conversions apply to everything, even the "unformatted" I/O functions such as `read` and `write`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually, all you need to do is 1) open streams as binary `istream fin(ios::in | ios::binary)`; 2) use `cin >> noskipws`. This way streams work as expected. Answering authors question, they always return same data with `read`.

Comment: Reading between the lines a bit, I wonder if the *real* question here is more like "I have this code that reads through a file, but the results I'm getting don't seem to match what I expect to be in the file, and the results are inconsistent". But without more details or some actual code or something, of course, that's just pure silly speculation...

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: That leaves you still dealing with encoding, e.g. UTF-8.  And there's no way around that.  The iostreams expose an API based on characters; they aren't intended for anything other than character data (strings).  (No, I'm not using "character" to mean `char`, I mean that the Standard actually defines streambufs based on characters).  Unformatted I/O does not mean binary.  `ios::binary` doesn't mean binary, either (and unfortunately).

Comment: @BenVoigt How does reading a bytestring (`char[]`) in binary mode differ from reading binary data?

Comment: "In order to support file I/O and multibyte/wide character  conversion, conversions are performed using members of a facet, referred to as `a_codecvt` in following sections"   All `streambuf` objects have this `codecvt` facet.  iostreams don't work with actual file contents, the way an OS API like `read` or `ReadFile` does, they work on a character sequence resulting from conversion.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph  All iostreams I/O functions ultimately go through the `underflow` and `overflow` function on the associated `streambuf`.  In section 27.9.1.5 of the Standard, you can see that  both `underflow` and `overflow` feed their data through the `codecvt` facet.